# Invoking method handler on another thread

Tags: c#, compact-framework, backgroundworker

I'm trying to implement my own basic BackgroundWorker, since the Compact Framework doesn't provide one, is it advisable to invoke the WorkCompletedHandler on the UI thread like this?

CustomBackgroundWorker Class:

```
public delegate void DoWorkHandler(object sender, DoWorkArgs e);
public delegate void WorkCompletedHandler(object sender, WorkCompletedArgs e);
class CustomBackgroundWorker
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.Control _owning_control;
        private System.Threading.Thread _t;
        private Exception _e = null;
        public event DoWorkHandler DoWork;
        public event WorkCompletedHandler WorkCompleted;

        public CustomBackgroundWorker(System.Windows.Forms.Control Owning_Control)
        {
            if (Owning_Control == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Owning_Control");
            _owning_control = Owning_Control;
        }
        public void RunWorkerAsync()
        {
            this.RunWorkerAsync(null);
        }
        public void RunWorkerAsync(object Parameter)
        {
            if (DoWork == null) throw new Exception("DoWork Event isn't subscribed.");
            DoWorkArgs dowork_args = new DoWorkArgs(Parameter);
            _t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DoWork(this, dowork_args);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _e = ex;
                    }
                    if (WorkCompleted != null)
                    {
                        _owning_control.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                WorkCompleted(this, new WorkCompletedArgs(_e, dowork_args.Result));
                            }));
                    }
                });
            _t.Name = "BackgroundWorker Thread";
            _t.Start();
        }
    }

    public class DoWorkArgs
    {
        public object Result { get; set; }
        public object Parameter { get; private set; }
        public DoWorkArgs(object Parameter)
        {
            this.Parameter = Parameter;
        }
    }

    public class WorkCompletedArgs
    {
        private object _result;
        public WorkCompletedArgs(Exception Error, object Result)
        {
            this.Error = Error;
            _result = Result;
        }
        public object Result
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Error != null) throw new Exception("Can't access Result, during execution an Exception was thrown.");
                return _result;
            }
        }
        public object Error { get; private set; }
    }
```

A sample usage:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "UI Thread!";
CustomBackgroundWorker bgw = new CustomBackgroundWorker(this);
bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkHandler((o, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Tick: " + i.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    args.Result = i;
                }
            });
 bgw.WorkCompleted += new WorkCompletedHandler((o, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            if (args.Error == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + args.Result.ToString());
            }
        });
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: It may or may not be useful, but be aware that [the actual source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs,85d60b0d93a826fa) for `BackgroundWorker` is available to inspect.

Comment: How do you plan to notify the parent when the backgroundworker completes?  I wish microsoft would include in these examples the main() method that calls the async methods.

Comment: @JamesThorpe That was interesting to read, but I don't think the AsyncOperation class is supported in the CF. Other than that it seems the actual BackgroundWorker is implemented similarly to what i posted.